# Facebook invite friends button for static html page

Tags: javascript, facebook, iframe

i'm having a problem with creating "invite your friends to this page"- button. I'm using static html iframe- application and i'd like to implement a button, which users can click and invite their friends to that same iframe tab. So, how can i implement such a button? i've tried alot of things, but can't seem to get this one work. Thanks in advance for the answers : )

i've tried things like the following:

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
FB.init({
    appId: "YOUR_APP_ID",
    status: true,
    cookie: true
});

// Additional initialization code here
};

// Load the SDK Asynchronously
(function(d){
    var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
    js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
    ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
}(document));

function invite() {
    FB.ui({
        method: "apprequests",
        message: "Check out my great app"
    }, inviteCallback);
}

function inviteCallback(response) {
console.log(response);
}
```

and i've tried to use the page id as app id but it's not working. Is there a way to use url instead of app id?

Comment: what exactly did you try? please use the facebook docs and google first, or tell us what you´ve tried so far.

Comment: Hey, i edited an example of what i've tried

Comment: so what is the response? and are you using invite() on user click?

Comment: about "url instead of app id" - of course not. you must use an app.

Comment: it says something like the following (translating from another language):

"The app configuration setting does not allow the given url: Atleast one of the given url is not allowed. It must match the site or basic site's url. "

Comment: ok, then it´s pretty clear. i will create an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error you mentioned in the comments indicates that you did not set up a platform in the App settings. Open the "Settings" tab in your App settings and click on the "Add Platform" button to add a platform (most likely "Website"). Enter the URL of your App in the "Site URL" input field.